# Start Fedora Server MATE Desktop

Tags: linux, fedora, xserver, mate-desktop

I wonder if it's possible to start the MATE Desktop when needed and don't set graphical.target as standard.

installing MATE Desktop is no problem with dnf group. But startx always says X Server is offline etc...

What am I doing wrong?! Sometimes I just don't want to do stuff with nano/vim etc...

Edit: Using Fedora 23 Server in Virtual Box (testing)

Comment: There are special graphics drivers you have to install from the VirtualBox extras. Anyways, this question is off-topic for StackOverflow because it isn't about programming

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should cover most bases:

1. `yum -y update kernel` and `reboot`
2. `yum -y install dkms kernel-devel kernel-headers`
3. `yum -y install epel-release`
4. `yum -y groups install "MATE Desktop"`
5. [Install the Virtual Box Guest additions](https://www.virtualbox.org/manual/ch04.html#idp46730490379936) and `reboot`

It's important to install the VirtualBox Guest Additions after installing MATE so that they find the X Server installation. That way they arrange the necessary graphical drivers. Finally, to avoid having to setup a graphical default target;

6. `echo "exec /usr/bin/mate-session" >> ~/.xinitrc`
7. `startx`

If you still get that "X Server is offline" issue then try `yum -y groupinstall "X Window System"` and reinstall the VirtualBox Guest Additions.

As was commented above, this would have been better asked on Unix & Linux. Comprehensive [instructions for installing various desktop environments](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/181504/102266) can be found there.